# Store array to file and load array from file in BASH

Tags: bash, array

I want to be able to store multiple integer arrays into a txt file when I'm done updating them, and then be able to load these arrays from the txt file into the script that I am using.

The arrays basically will contain certain statistics and I want to be able to load and save them so that they update the statistics after each execution of the script.

Is there any way to do this in bash?

EDIT: to the answer below, how would you write the arrays to the file?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have a file with two integer arrays, one per line:

```
$ cat file
1 20 300
1 2 3 5
```

We can read those arrays in as follows:

```
{ read -a a1; read -a a2; } <file
```

We can verify that they were read correctly using `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p a1
declare -a a1='([0]="1" [1]="20" [2]="300")'
$ declare -p a2
declare -a a2='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="5")'
```

#### Saving arrays to file

One way to save them to file is:

```
$ { echo "${a1[*]}"; echo "${a2[*]}"; } >newfile
```

The resulting file looks like:

```
$ cat newfile
1 20 300
1 2 3 5
```

Comment: @layshal Answer updated with a method for writing to file.

Comment: Just use `declare -p a1 a2 > file` and `. file`. `declare -p` gives exact and perfectly bash-reusable output.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the arrays to the file with

```
printf "%s\n" "${a1[*]}" "${a2[*]}" > file
```

This is compatible with John1024's answer; it puts one array per line.